# Create a dictionary {week1: game1, game2, game3, ect} that seperates sports fixtures from a list [[game1],[game2]],[[game1],[game2]

Tags: python

Apologise if I make any mistakes, or miss any info off, this is my first question on stackoverflow.

I am trying to create a python program that creates fixtures, in a round robin style. The overall spec will be: a user inputs team name (no set number of teams), the programme then create a dictionary that is split up by 'weeks', or different rotation of permutations. i.e. week 1(1v2 3v4 5v6), week 2(2v3 4v5 6v1), week 3(3v4 5v6 2v) ect... and where possible no team will play home, home or away away. I know this is only possible when the number of teams / 2 is even, when odd no team plays home and away more than twice in a row.

I have coded the individual games creator (i.e. 1v2 3v4 5v6 ect...) code below

```
teams = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

if len(teams) % 2:
    teams.append('Rest week')
n = len(teams)
matchs = []
fixtures = []
return_matchs = []
for fixture in range(1, n):
    for i in range(n//2):
       matchs.append([teams[i], teams[n - 1 - i]])
       return_matchs.append([teams[n - 1 - i], teams[i]])
    teams.insert(1, teams.pop())
    fixtures.insert(len(fixtures)//2, matchs)
    fixtures.append(return_matchs)
    matchs = []
    return_matchs = []
```

I have created a 'teams' list but for ease of testing.
The output when print(fixtures) is:

```
[[['1 v Rest week'], ['2 v 9'], ['3 v 8'], ['4 v 7'], ['5 v 6']], [['1 v 9'], ['Rest week v 8'], ['2 v 7'], ['3 v 6'], ['4 v 5']], [['1 v 8'], ['9 v 7'], ['Rest week v 6'], ['2 v 5'], ['3 v 4']], [['1 v 7'], ['8 v 6'], ['9 v 5'], ['Rest week v 4'], ['2 v 3']] ... cut ...
```

I have cut for brevity.
Obviously this code works how I would like it to work, but if anyone has any advice or suggestions I would certainly appreciate that.

The problem i have is splitting this list into a dictionary, like i mentioned above. For ease of reading, im looking for

```
[[['1 v Rest week'], ['2 v 9'], ['3 v 8'], ['4 v 7'], ['5 v 6']], [['1 v 9'], ['Rest week v 8'], ['2 v 7'], ['3 v 6'], ['4 v 5']] ...]
```

to turn into

```
{week1: [['1 v Rest week'], ['2 v 9'], ['3 v 8'], ['4 v 7'], ['5 v 6']], week2: [['9 v 1'], ['8 v Rest week'], ['7 v 2'], ['6 v 3'], ['5 v 4']] ...}
```

What I have done is

```
weekDict = {}

weekDict.update({'week1': fixtures[0]})
weekDict.update(({'week2': fixtures[-1]}))
weekDict.update(({'week3': fixtures[1]}))
weekDict.update(({'week4': fixtures[-2]}))
weekDict.update(({'week5': fixtures[2]}))
...
```

That is very very long winded and very impractical if the number of team changes. This code does give the output kind of what im looking for.

```
{'week1': [['1 v Rest week'], ['2 v 9'], ['3 v 8'], ['4 v 7'], ['5 v 6']], 
'week2': [['2 v 1'], ['Rest week v 3'], ['9 v 4'], ['8 v 5'], ['7 v 6']], 
'week3': [['1 v 9'], ['Rest week v 8'], ['2 v 7'], ['3 v 6'], ['4 v 5']], 
'week4': [['3 v 1'], ['2 v 4'], ['Rest week v 5'], ['9 v 6'], ['8 v 7']], 
'week5': [['1 v 8'], ['9 v 7'], ['Rest week v 6'], ['2 v 5'], ['3 v 4']]}
```

It doesnt do the home and away, so any help on that would be good.
Is there an easier way to get what im looking for. I have tried a couple of for loops, example below

```
for fixture in fixtures:
    weekDict = {}
    for i in range(len(fixtures)):
        i = 0
        num = 1
        weekDict.update({'week' + str(num): fixtures[i]})
        num += 1
        i += 1
print(weekDict)
```

which gives

```
{'week1': [['1', 'Rest week'], ['2', '9'], ['3', '8'], ['4', '7'], ['5', '6']]}
```

Im stuck! Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't need the second loop over fixtures. You almost did it(keep it up), you just got your for loop wrong.

```
weekDict = {}

for ind, fixture in enumerate(fixtures):
    weekDict.update({'week'+str(ind+1):fixture})

print(weekDict)
```